# What is this photo FX and what app can do this?

Tags: photo-editing, effects

Saw this on a twitter's celebrity. How do you achieve this? What phone app could do this? Many thanks [image]

Comment: If you search for "anaglyph effect", you'll likely find a phone app that can do it. For example, [the Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=anaglyph%20effect&c=apps&hl=en&gl=US) shows several. Just a note, this probably isn't a real 3D anaglyph, but a fake anaglyph effect.

Answer (score 1):

It has 3 copies of the image in separate layers, moved horizontally a half of the face width apart and colorized differently.

[image]

They are combined with layer blending mode ADD - the top layer (=Original) which contains in the middle placed non-colorized version, has it.

In the left there's the red version and in the right there's the cyan version. One gets them by applying Image > Adjust > Hue/Saturation > Colorize in Photoshop:

[image]

Alternative: Colorization to red is possible also by closing the green and blue channels of an RGB image. Coloring to cyan happens when one closes the red channel. Photoshop's Hue/Saturation > Colorize gives more control.

The background of the faces are removed and finally a new black background is inserted.

Layer blending mode ADD causes easily clipping. Both colorized versions have a masked curves layer (with the next image layer only -switch ON) to reduce their brightnesses on the areas below the original.

The half-cyan slice on the middle version does not look right, it should be neutral. One can reduce the saturation of the cyan version below the original with another adjustment layer:

[image]

In theory this could be made as well in GIMP, Krita, Paint.NET etc... but making it is handy only in programs which have adjustment layers and layer masks. Krita and web service Photopea are such ones available for free.